# How to find if a model was saved from Django Admin, or elsewhere

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Is there a way to identify if the current `save()` or `post_save` happened via Django Admin? I want to do something differently for models saved via Admin, than models saved from my Django Rest Framework API.

Specifically, I have a `create_related_objects` I call on `post_save` of model `Transaction`, to create related object `CalendarInfo`.

But when creating `Transaction` via Admin, because the related `CalendarInfo` object is an inline, I don't need to call that `create_related_objects` on the `Transaction` model's `post_save`.

Comment: maybe you should try changing the save_model method https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model. Here you receive ModelForm, Http request and check them to see if its coming from UI or API

Comment: maybe you should remove the post_save signal. Do the related model creation in the serializer create

Comment: @e4c5 that is the approach I am going with finally - model creation in serializer create, and admin customization in add_view and create_view. If you can write up your comment as an answer, would be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't need to create the related model thanks to the presence of the `InlineAdmin` perhaps it would be better for you to remove the post_save signal receiver rather than adding more code inside post_save to determine where the save originated from.

That way you can just place a call to `create_related_models` in your serializer's create method to achieve the same objective.

Answer (score 2):

From documentation:

> [ModelAdmin.response_add](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.response_add) is called after the admin form is
>   submitted and just after the object and all the related instances have
>   been created and saved. You can override it to change the default
>   behavior after the object has been created.

by overriding `the response_add` method in your `ModelAdmin` class you can execute a code after something in the admin got added successfully.